# how can i make this kind of animation in .cs code file?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-mobile, windows-phone-7.1

```
    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1" Completed="Storyboard1_Completed">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="imageBack1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.25" Value="90"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="imageBack1">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.25">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" To="90" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="image1" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
    </Storyboard>
```

i am doing something like this

```
    private Timeline CreateFlipAnimation(TimeSpan beginTime, UIElement target, UIElement target2) 
    {
        DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames animation = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames(){
            BeginTime = beginTime
        };

        //target.Projection = new PlaneProjection();
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(UIElement.ProjectionProperty));
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, target);
        animation.KeyFrames.Add(new EasingDoubleKeyFrame() { KeyTime = kt1, Value = 90 });
        animation.KeyFrames.Add(new EasingDoubleKeyFrame() { KeyTime = kt2, Value = 0 });

        ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames animation1 = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames()
        {
            BeginTime = beginTime
        };
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation1, new PropertyPath(UIElement.VisibilityProperty));
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation1, target);
        animation1.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame() { KeyTime = kt1, Value = Visibility.Visible });

        DoubleAnimation animation2 = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            //Duration = , 
            To = 90
        };
        //target2.Projection = new PlaneProjection();
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation2, new PropertyPath(UIElement.ProjectionProperty));
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation2, target2);


    }
```

now i don't know how can i put this in .cs file

```
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="imageBack1">
```

i have commented the section so tell me how can i proceed with this...?
also in duration how should i initialize the value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good news: you're almost doing the right thing already!

This Ruby script does lots of animation like you are looking to do: http://script.iron7.com/#/Script/Detail?scriptId=81baa9940368436c8244ab7810331b65&userLowerCaseName=iron7

Video - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5k8SG82e1Rc

The code basically does the equivalent of:

```
target2.Projection = new PlaneProjection();
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation2, new PropertyPath(PlaneProjection.RotationZProperty));
Storyboard.SetTarget(animation2, target2.Projection);
```

For setting the Duration, you can just set that up using Duration in your DoubleAnimation - or in the KeyFrame KeyTimes in a DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames